# AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID memory leak?

Tags: iphone

I just started using Instruments and its Leak detection feature. I was monitoring my code and I noticed there is a leak when I call the method:

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID

I am basically using the SoundEffect.m file from the Metronome sample code. I am using a soundfile that was originally a .wav and I converted it using Itunes to a aif and renamed it a caf. It plays just fine and it wasn't until I ran Instruments that I realized there was a leak.

The odd thing is that, when I use a different sound file (tick.caf - from Mentronome sample project) - there is no leak. The same issue is described here with no real answer as to why:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8360344

Anyways, is there any reason why my sound file would cause a leak? Is Audio Toolkit particularly picky about the audio file it is trying to play??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it would cause a leak, but perhaps there is a bug in AudioServices when playing an `aiff` file named as `caf`. Try converting using `afconvert` to produce a real `caf` file from your mac:

```
afconvert -f caff -d ima4 input.mp3 output.caf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID to dispose.